# How to close a non-blocking socket?

Tags: linux, sockets, freebsd, nonblocking

I believe that if we call close system call on a non-blocking socket it returns immediately, then how to handle the response? whether it is closed or not?
in other words what is the behavior of the socket system call close on a non-blocking socket?

Comment: What OS are you using and what language?

Comment: Linux (freebsd) and C language

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> if we call close system call on a
>   non-blocking socket it returns
>   immediately

The *socket* is always closed: the *connection* may still be writing to the peer. But your question embodies a fallacy: if you call close() on *any* socket it will return immediately. Closing and writing to a socket is asynchronous. You can control that with SO_LINGER as per the other answer, although I suspect that only applies to blocking mode. Probably you should put the socket back into blocking mode before closing with a positive SO_LINGER if that's what you need to do.

Answer (score 8):

It's not the blocking state of the socket, it's the `SO_LINGER` option that matters. From [`getsockopt(2)`](http://www.FreeBSD.org/cgi/man.cgi?query=setsockopt&apropos=0&sektion=0&manpath=FreeBSD%208.2-RELEASE&format=html):

> `SO_LINGER` controls the action taken when unsent messages are queued on
>        socket and a `close(2)` is performed.  If the socket promises reliable
>        delivery of data and `SO_LINGER` is set, the system will block the process
>        on the `close(2)` attempt until it is able to transmit the data or until it
>        decides it is unable to deliver the information (a timeout period, termed
>        the linger interval, is specified in seconds in the `setsockopt()` system
>        call when `SO_LINGER` is requested).  If `SO_LINGER` is disabled and a
>        `close(2)` is issued, the system will process the close in a manner that
>        allows the process to continue as quickly as possible.

That is, with `SO_LINGER` enabled an error from `close(2)` on TCP socket would mean that kernel was not able to deliver data within linger interval (not counting other errors like invalid file descriptor, etc.). With lingering disabled - you never know. Also see [The ultimate SO_LINGER page, or why is my tcp not reliable](http://www.archive.org/22/items/TheUltimateSo_lingerPageOrWhyIsMyTcpNotReliable/the-ultimate-so_linger-page-or-why-is-my-tcp-not-reliable.html).

Comment: So you are saying, that a close call with a positiv linger time will block, even if the socket is set to non-blocking mode? I was under the impression, that in that case, close will not block either and the linger time is just the amount of time that may pass before the socket is really closed in kernel space, yet in user space the socket is closed immediately and thus close will not block for non-blocking sockets.

Comment: @Mecki No, it will not block, it will return -1 with `errno == EAGAIN/EWOULDBLOCK` if there is data pending. This is a very murky area.

Answer (score 0):

@user207421 - your answer is wrong. If the socket is in blocking mode, and the TCP window is full/the write buffer is full, close() WILL block because the FIN packet requires SEQ and ACK numbers. In case of a non blocking socket, you get EAGAIN.
However, with no-lingering turned on, close() will send not a FIN but RST packet and it does not use SEQ/ACK. RST packet will be sent immediately, and the contents of write buffer will be simply discarded. SO_LINGER has nothing - really nothing - to do with blocking or non-blocking modi.

Comment: Try to shut down the socket using WSAsendDisconnect function.<br>

Comment: Needing a sequence number doesn’t imply that the FIN needs send buffer space. And tell us: if you have a positive SO_LINGER timeout set and you’re in non-blocking mode, will it or won’t it block?