# Can close() block execution for some period of time?

Tags: c, linux

I am writing a small networking program where latency is very important. I would like to catch all possible cases where execution is blocked in some system call.

I know that `connect` can block execution for several seconds. `read` blocks until data is available. `write` blocks until there is enough of space in system buffers. The question is: can `close` block execution for some time? If yes, is this solved by using non-blocking sockets?

I am working on Linux. However, it is interesting to learn about other systems as well.

Comment: Yes, `close` can block as well. If you don't want blocking behavior, use non-blocking sockets. Works for all of those situations.

Comment: @JoachimPileborg: If `close` on a non-blocking socket does not block, can I be sure that the connection was closed properly if zero is returned?

Comment: Okay, I misunderstood the reason of why a `close` call can block, it's nothing to do with the sockets blocking or non-blocking status but is controlled with the `SO_LINGER` socket option. See e.g. [this old SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418277/how-to-close-a-non-blocking-socket).

Answer (score 2):

Yes close can block. It happens when there is another thread blocked on recv/send call on same socket.

Use non-blocking sockets to avoid this.