# Are there any cases when TcpClient.Close or Socket.Close(0) could block my code?

Tags: c#, sockets, tcpclient

As it's not specified that Close method is thread safe I should call it from the lock. How can I be sure that it will not block my thread? Should I disable LingerState or can it be enabled?

btw do I need to call both TcpClient.Close and TcpClient.Client.Close?

Comment: Have you considered putting socket code in its own thread? Or perhaps using the TPL?

Comment: In a high performance server environment I can't allocate a new thread each time I have new connection.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation for TcpClient.Close](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.close.aspx), calling this method disposes the instance.  A quick look in ILSpy reveals that it simply calls `Dispose`, which calls `Dispose(true)`.

Furthermore, the documentation states that calling `Close` also disposes of the underlying `Socket`.

In fact, before disposing of the `Socket`, it calls [Shutdown(SocketShutdown.Both)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.socket.shutdown.aspx).

Given that .NET sockets are wrappers for Windows sockets, the [shutdown](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms740481.aspx) function is also called, and its documentation states:

> **Note** The shutdown function does not block regardless of the SO_LINGER setting on the socket.

However, the `Socket` overloads its `Close` method to accept a *timeout* parameter and similar to `TcpClient`, the `Socket.Close` method calls `Socket.Dispose(true)`, which uses the *timeout* value to determine whether or not it may block.

According to the [documentation for Socket.Close(int)](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bc68k4td.aspx):

> If you need to call Close without first calling Shutdown, you can ensure that data queued for outgoing transmission will be sent by setting the DontLinger option to false and specifying a non-zero time-out interval. Close will then block until this data is sent or until the specified time-out expires. If you set DontLinger to false and specify a zero time-out interval, Close releases the connection and automatically discards outgoing queued data.

Apparently, neither `TcpClient` or `Socket` expose the *timeout* value to you as a settable property and the default value is not `0`; therefore, it would seem that to avoid blocking you must call `Socket.Close(0)` yourself prior to calling `TcpClient.Close`.

Keep in mind that `Close` can also throw a `SocketException`, despite the Framework Design Guideline's recommendation to never throw in a call to `Dispose`.  Perhaps that's one of the reasons why it's named `Close` and `TcpClient` explicitly implements the `Dispose` method.

Comment: I checked that if I use TcpClient.Client.Close(1000) it blocks. But if I set TcpClient.LingerState (true, 1000) it doesn't block when I call TcpClient.Close() or TcpClient.Client.Close() without arguments. Does it mean that I can still use linger option but avoid blocking  (simple closing TcpClient with Close())?

Comment: When you tested, was there data in the buffer that wasn't sent yet?

Comment: It seems to me that unless you explicitly specify Close(0) there's a chance that it will block.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.lingeroption(v=vs.110).aspx
> The IP stack computes the default IP protocol time-out period to use based on the round trip time of the connection. In most cases, the time-out computed by the stack is more relevant than one defined by an application. This is the default behavior for a Socket when the LingerState property is not set and for a TcpClient when the LingerState property is not set.

Comment: 1) "was there data in the buffer that wasn't sent yet" - there was a data that wasn't received on another side (no Receive call). I'm not sure whether I can control it to be "not sent". Hm.. I've rechecked it. It seems like it doesn't matter if data was received - it still blocks after Receive(). 2) that documentation says that the data will be sent when closing the socket but it does not say that it's done in a blocking way...

Comment: Found out it. I should disable linger: "SO_LINGER controls the action taken when unsent messages are queued on socket and a close(2) is performed. The system will block the process on the close(2) attempt until it is able to transmit the data or a timeout period. If SO_LINGER is disabled and a close(2) is issued, the system will process the close in a manner that allows the process to continue as quickly as possible."

Comment: I looked in ILSpy.  It literally compares the closing timeout to 0 and if true it disposes of the socket (handle) and does nothing else; otherwise, it may follow a path that ends up looping on (!this.m_Released) and doing a Thread.SpinWait(1).

Regardless, I think the documentation is very clear.  It discusses blocking on Close and it provides an overload with a timeout.  What more do you expect?  E.g., see also [closesocket function](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms737582(v=vs.85).aspx).

Comment: Great, which documentation was that?

Comment: FreeBSD Man, mentioned in the second answer of 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6418277/how-to-close-a-non-blocking-socket

Comment: FYI, [linger is disabled by default](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.sockets.tcpclient.lingerstate(v=vs.110).aspx).  I believe you should only have to call Close(0), as I stated previously.